# Fit the width of the graph output by prophet to the window of shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to display the graph created by prophet in R language with shiny.

However, when the graph output by prophet is displayed in shiny, the width of the graph is smaller than the window size, and large blank spaces may be created on the left and right.

How can I fit the width of the graph to the window size?

```
library(prophet)
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(
  ds = seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "month"),
  y = sample(60)
)

m <- prophet(df)
future <- predict(m, data.frame(ds = df[, 1]))


ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot.prophet")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot.prophet <- renderPlot({plot(m, future)})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[The width of the graph is smaller than the window size, and there are large blank spaces on the left and right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eflen.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your `ui` you need to specify the width of the plot.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot.prophet", width = "100%")
)
```

Comment: I tried "width = 100%", but it left blanks on the left and right as I did without the option.